# How to add custom delay to instaloader

Tags: timer, rate-limiting, instaloader

can someone show me how to add a time delay to instaloader.py a code snippet of a working time delay inside the instaloadercontext.py i just want to add  a custom delay once a return limit of 60 is reached to `do_sleep` for an hour before the next query.

in the below code ,class `RateController` is  providing request tracking and rate controlling to stay within rate limits.

It can be overridden to change Instaloader's behavior regarding rate limits, for example to raise a custom exception when the rate limit is hit

```
   import instaloader

   class MyRateController(instaloader.RateController):
       def sleep(self, secs):
           raise MyCustomException()

   L = instaloader.Instaloader(rate_controller=lambda ctx: MyRateController(ctx))
```